# PHP Mail function doesn't work from command line but works when called from www

Tags: php, email, sendmail, cpanel

I have a script hosted at a site using CPanel. It stopped working a few days ago, not sure if it's because of an update but I can't find anything.

The script basically calls `mail($email, "Testing", "This is a test")`. This code works when I invoke it from the browser (i.e. I get the email) but not from the command line. It doesn't show any errors and I am not getting any email as well.

Can someone help?

Thanks

Comment: There is a different php.ini for the web and the cli interpreter. Compare the settings via `phpinfo()` and `php -i`.

Answer (score 1):

Command line PHP and web server PHP normally have different configuration directives, with different privileges enabled or disabled.
Take a look at the php.ini file for more information, there the different settings can be ...set.

And do as mario suggest too, ask phpinfo() (in web server) and php -i (in CLI);